# Momentjs start of day off by 4 minutes?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, momentjs

this is exactly what i am putting into the chrome console:

```
moment().startOf("day").format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:ss')
"04/27/2015 00:04:00"
```

why could this be happening??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because `MM` in `HH:MM:ss` refers to the two digit month ([see docs for `format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)). And we are currently in April. :-)

Try `mm` instead.